# Minimum of $\sum_{i=1}^np_i\log(p_i)$ (negative of the Entropy)

Tags: calculus, statistics, entropy

Prove that for given $t \in (0,1)$ and $ x \in (0,t)  $
the function $f$ will have its minimum when $x = \frac{t}{2}$

$$
f(x) = x\log(x) + (t-x)\log(t-x) 
$$
Therefore the minimum is $ f(\frac{t}{2}) = t\log(\frac{t}{2})
$

The reason is asking is because I want to understand why [Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Definition) is maximized when the probability is uniformly distributed.

The negative of the Entropy is: $\sum_{i=1}^np_i\log(p_i)$

For a more complete answer check: [Why is Entropy maximised when the probability distribution is uniform?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66108/why-is-entropy-maximised-when-the-probability-distribution-is-uniform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=\frac{t}{2}$ is the only critical point of $f$ in $(0;t)$:

$$
f'=\log(x)+1-\log(t-x)-1=\log\frac{x}{t-x}
$$

so $f'=0$ means $x=t-x$.

The second derivative $f''=\frac1x+\frac1{t-x}>0$ on $(0;t)$, so $\frac{t}2$ is the only minimum.

Comment: Could you generalize that for n variables? I added a link to the general case in my question.